# Migrate from Oracle to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, import, migration, dump

We ran into serious performance problems with our Oracle database and we would like to try to migrate it to a MySQL-based database (either MySQL directly or, more preferably, Infobright).

The thing is, we need to let the old and the new system overlap for at least some weeks if not months, before we actually know, if all the features of the new database match our needs.

So, here is our situation:

The Oracle database consists of multiple tables with each millions of rows. During the day, there are literally thousands of statements, which we cannot stop for migration.

Every morning, new data is imported into the Oracle database, replacing some thousands of rows. Copying this process is not a problem, so we could, in theory, import in both databases in parallel.

But, and here the challenge lies, for this to work we need to have an export from the Oracle database with a consistent state from one day. (We cannot export some tables on Monday and some others on Tuesday, etc.) This means, that at least the export should be finished in less than one day.

Our first thought was to dump the schema, but I wasn't able to find a tool to import an Oracle dump file into MySQL. Exporting tables in CSV files might work, but I'm afraid it could take too long.

So my question now is:

What should I do? Is there any tool to import Oracle dump files into MySQL? Does anybody have any experience with such a large-scale migration?

PS: Please, don't suggest performance optimization techniques for Oracle, we already tried a lot :-)

*Edit:* We already tried some ETL tools before, only to find out, that they were not fast enough: Exporting only one table already took more than 4 hours ...

**2nd Edit:** Come on folks ... did nobody ever try to export a whole database as fast as possible and convert the data so that it can be imported into another database system?

Comment: So Oracle can't handle your workload so you are switching to MySQL? Is this a joke? If its not, I think Larry needs to know about this right away so he can put a stop to it. Larry's answer would be you need to throw more money at it adding load balancing etc.

But seriously, I think your first priority would be making sure MySQL could handle the workload.

Comment: I never said Oracle couldn't handle it, Oracle simply has its limitations. And as I said, we want to try alternatives. For our tasks at hand, Oracle might not be the most appropriate database system, a "data warehouse" optimized system could possibly perform better. We tried Sand some years ago and were stunned by the performance gain, but it was simply too expensive. Infobright goes the same way (column-centric data organisation) and is a lot cheaper. What we're trying here is simply to compare these two approaches under the same preconditions.

Comment: If this goes through and you really migrate AND have performance improvements you should write a lengthy blog post with plenty of details. I would love to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: Been doing a migration at work (PostgreSQL -> Oracle) and I know how slow it can be. Our DB is probably much more static, sounds like it's smaller, and it's all being done by PHP scripts transferring the data across, editing it a bit as it goes.

I'd be interested to see what works here for you.

Comment: Database replication is not a programming problem.  Voting to migrate to Server Fault.

Comment: Careful now. Oracle owns MySQL. Piss off Larry and he'll hose MySQL then you'll be migrating to Excel spreadsheets :) Good luck with this. All the best.

Comment: After reading all the responses, could you specify how much data is involved? Why not export to csv and use MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle does not supply an out-of-the-box unload utility.

Keep in mind without comprehensive info about your environment (oracle version? server platform? how much data? what datatypes?) everything here is YMMV and you would want to give it a go on your system for performance and timing.

My points 1-3 are just generic data movement ideas. Point 4 is a method that will reduce downtime or interruption to minutes or seconds.

1) There are 3rd party utilities available. I have used a few of these but best for you to check them out yourself for your intended purpose. A few 3rd party products are listed here: [OraFaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#Is_there_a_SQL.2AUnloader_to_download_data_to_a_flat_file.3F) . Unfortunately a lot of them run on Windows which would slow down the data unload process unless your DB server was on windows and you could run the load utility directly on the server.

2) If you don't have any complex datatypes like LOBs then you can roll your own with SQLPLUS. If you did a table at a time then you can easily parallelize it. Topic has been visited on this site probably more than once, here is an example: [Linky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)

3) If you are 10g+ then External Tables might be a performant way to accomplish this task. If you create some blank external tables with the same structure as your current tables and copy the data to them, the data will be converted to the external table format (a text file). Once again, OraFAQ to the [rescue](http://www.orafaq.com/node/848).

4) If you must keep systems in parallel for days/weeks/months then use a change data capture/apply tool for near-zero downtime. Be prepared to pay $$$. I have used Golden Gate Software's tool that can mine the Oracle redo logs and supply insert/update statements to a MySQL Database. You can migrate the bulk of the data with no downtime the week before go-live. Then during your go-live period, shut down the source database, have Golden Gate catch up the last remaining transactions, then open up access to your new target database. I have used this for upgrades and the catch up period was only a few minutes. We already had a site licenses for Golden Gate so it wasn't anything out of pocket for us.

And I'll play the role of Cranky DBA here and say if you can't get Oracle performing well I would love to see a write up of how MySQL fixed your particular issues. If you have an application where you can't touch the SQL, there are still lots of possible ways to tune Oracle. /soapbox

Answer (score 5):

I have built a C# application that can read an Oracle dump (.dmp) file and pump it's tables of data into a SQL Server database.

This application is used nightly on a production basis to migrate a PeopleSoft database to SQL Server.  The PeopleSoft database has 1100+ database tables and the Oracle dump file is greater than 4.5GB in size.

This application creates the SQL Server database and tables and then loads all 4.5GB of data in less than 55 minutes running on a dual-core Intel server.

I don't believe it would be too difficult to modify this application to work with other databases provided they have an ADO.NET provider.

Comment: That sounds promising. Sadly I don't get to try that, as I have moved on to another company where I don't have the problem any more. However, maybe you could publish your results as a blog post? I'd love to see some stats.

Comment: Good of you to comment on an answer to an ancient post, Dan.  Much appreciate the vote-up.  I'm hoping that sometime in the near future, someone else may see this and be able to make use of it.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Out of interest, how are you finding the SQL Server performance compares to Oracle. I have used both but never on a database similar enough to compare like for like.

Comment: @ChrisProsser - Unfortunately, I'm not sure. I'm not a dba, so didn't have the opportunity to make that determination.  I can tell you that it performed well enough to allow the customer to drop their Oracle installation and migrate to SQL Server completely, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 3):

yeah, Oracle is pretty slow. :)

You can use any number of ETL tools to move data from Oracle into MySQL. My favourite is SQL Server Integration Services.

If you have Oracle9i or higher, you can implement Change Data Capture. Read more here http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10736/cdc.htm

Then you can take a delta of changes from Oracle to your MySQL or Infobright using any ETL technologies.

Comment: The ETL tools we already tried were far too slow. As I wrote, we need to export the complete database in less than one day. Amended my question, but still thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you for the link. This still leaves open the question how to export and import the initial data ...

Comment: The initial data should be a snapshot taken at a particular time. A backup is one such snapshot data. You will only take the changed data after the time of the backup.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue. Needed to get tables and data from oracle dbms to mysql dbms.

We used this tool we found online... It worked well.

http://www.sqlines.com/download

This tool will basically help you:

1. Connect to your source DBMS(ORACLE)
2. Connect to destination DBMS(MySQL)
3. Specify schema and tables in the ORACLE DBMS you want to migrate
4. Press a "Transfer" button to Run the migration process(running inbuilt migration queries)
5. Get a transfer log, which will tell how many records were READ from SOURCE and WRITTEN on the destination database, what queries failed.

Hope this will help others that will land on this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Pentaho Data Integration to migrate from Oracle to MySql (I also migrated the same data to Postresql, which was about 50% quicker, which I guess was largely due to the different JDBC drivers being used). I followed Roland Bouman's instructions here, almost to the letter, and was very pleasantly suprised at how easy it was:

[Copy Table data from one DB to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060823/copy-table-data-from-one-db-to-another/2060837#2060837)

I don't know whether it will be appropriate for your data load, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I recently released [etlalchemy](https://github.com/seanharr11/etlalchemy) to accomplish this task. It is an open-sourced solution which allows migration between any 2 SQL databases with **4 lines of Python**, and was initially designed to migrate from Oracle to MySQL. Support has been added for MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite and SQL Server.

This will take care of migrating schema (arguably the most challenging), data, indexes and constraints, with many more options available.

To install:

```
$ pip install etlalchemy
```

*On El Capitan*: `pip install --ignore-installed etlalchemy`

To run:

```py
from etlalchemy import ETLAlchemySource, ETLAlchemyTarget

orcl_db_source = ETLAlchemySource("oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@hostname/ORACLE_SID")

mysql_db_target = ETLAlchemyTarget("mysql://username:password@hostname/db_name", drop_database=True)
mysql_db_target.addSource(orcl_db_source)
mysql_db_target.migrate()
```

Concerning **performance**, this tool utilizes BULK import tools across various RDBMS such as **mysqlimport** and **COPY FROM** (*postgresql*) to carry out migrations efficiently. I was able to migrate a 5GB SQL Server database with 33,105,951 rows into MySQL in 40 minutes, and a 3GB 7,000,000 row Oracle database to MySQL in 13 minutes.

To get more background on the origins of the project, [check out this post.](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/migrating-between-databases-with-etlalchemy) If you get any errors running the tool, open an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/seanharr11/etlalchemy/issues) and I'll patch it up in less than a week!

(To install the "cx_Oracle" Python driver, [follow these instructions](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/oracle/install-cx_oracle-mac))

Comment: Hi I tried with your script, but getting following error. I am new to Python Scripting, I have installed Python and created script with name as `abc.py`, when i run the script, its shows error as - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ETLAlchemySource'`

Comment: Make sure you are using python2.7

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.3.

Comment: That is not supported, install python2.7 and that will fix your problem

Comment: OK. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python, SQL*Plus and `mysql.exe` (MySQL client) script to copy whole table of just query results.
It will be portable because all those tools exist on Windows and Linux.

When I had to do it I implemented following steps using Python:

1. Extract data into CSV file using SQL*Plus.
2. Load dump file into MySQL
   using mysql.exe.

You can improve performance by performing parallel load using Tables/Partitions/Sub-partitions.

Disclosure: [Oracle-to-MySQL-Data-Migrator](https://github.com/alexbuz/Oracle-to-MySQL-DataMigrator/blob/master/README.txt) is the script I wrote for data integration between `Oracle and MySQL` on Windows OS.