# How to translate a MySQL database dump to new PG database?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a MySQL database with over 40,000 records I want to import into a new PostgreSQL database; I want to be able to map the values from the old table and column names into new table and column names... how do I do this?

For instance, I want to take this:

```
Table name: Horribly_Named_Table
=> Horribly_Named_Column: value1

(MySQL)
```

... and translate it to this:

```
Table name: better_named_table
=> better_named_column: value1

(PostgreSQL)
```

I've never done a move like this before, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a simple transformation within Pentaho Data Integration: setup is very simple and there is a wizard for loading database base data from one database to another:

See a similar answer here:

[Migrate from Oracle to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479500/migrate-from-oracle-to-mysql/2480398#2480398)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only referring to the difference in UPPER/lowercase names, then you don't really need to do something.

Just make sure you are not quoting the table names and they will not be case sensitive.

`This_Table_Name` is the same as `this_table_name` and that is the same as `THIS_TABLE_NAME`.

But `"this_table_name"` is something different then `"This_Table_Name"`

Comment: Note that a mysql dump may add ` marks around table / column names.  Just use a text editor or awk or sed to remove those marks and you're gold

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump has a [compatibility mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible), check "ansi" and "postgresql".